# Restrict Android application to Android TV

Tags: android, google-tv, android-tv

I'm implementing an application just specific to Android TV.
I use 2 features in AndoridManifiest.xml

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
        android:name="com.google.android.tv"
        android:required="true" />
```

It already published to Play Store. But I can not see my application when searching it via Play Store in Toshiba TV, Android Box that running Android OS.
How can I do like Youtube for TV application? It's specific only to Android TV (Google TV, Toshiba, Android Box).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your application name?

Answer (score 3):

For Android TV like Nexus Player the following is recommended in your manifest. It'll help filter your app in Play Store to Android TV devices only.

```
<application
    ...
    <activity
        android:name=".Mainctivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon_your_company"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/app_icon_your_company"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    ...
</application>

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />
```

Comment: This is just for devices like Android TV running Android 5.0. How about the other devices (TCL, Toshibar, Android Box...) running previous Android version .

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be restricted to just TV devices only.  There is a list of features that every Android TV or similar device needs to implement.  Unfortunately not all of these are clearly documented on Google site, but found in some of their code examples.   These should also help restrict items on Amazon Fire TV devices as well.

```
<feature name="android.hardware.location" />
<feature name="android.hardware.location.network" />
<feature name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" />
<feature name="android.hardware.type.television" />
<feature name="android.software.app_widgets" />
<feature name="android.software.backup" />
<feature name="android.software.leanback" />
<feature name="android.software.leanback_only" />
<feature name="android.software.live_tv" />
<feature name="android.software.print" />
<feature name="android.software.voice_recognizers" />
```

The one of the important ones here is android.hardware.type.television.  If you want to restrict things that make sure to set restrictions on the ones that you require for your app.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.television"
   android:required="true" />
```

If you app requires that system have all the Android Leanback functionality in place, then you want to enable support for leanback.

```
  <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback"
   android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback_only"
   android:required="false" />
```

You may want to set these to true if you only support Android TV devices, but leave them as optional if you are targeting Amazon FireTV devices.

Amazon FireTV supported Filters: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/app-submission/supported-filters-on-the-amazon-appstore.html

Google Android TV Core TV Hardware profile: https://android.googlesource.com/device/google/atv/+/578751f94fdc584be22d7b1ea3112723a861b3af/tv_core_hardware.xml

NVIDA Shield: https://developer.nvidia.com/android-tv-deployment-checklist

Answer (score 1):

You could restrict the devices in the [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/). Check also the [FAQ of Google](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1286017).

> The Device Availability dialog is a powerful tool available to all Android developers. It can be accessed from within the [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/). Device Availability provides a dynamic list of compatible devices based upon your manifest settings. For example, if your APK's manifest file specifies a large screen size, the console will reflect the supported devices that can find your app in Google Play. You can also use the dynamic search feature to see the devices that your application will not be available to. You can search by manufacturer, design name (ie. Passion), or the actual public device name (ie. Nexus One) to see if your manifest settings filtered a device.

Comment: There are many devices such as smart TV, set top box running Android OS. I can not check the supported devices one by one. :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you set the `leanback` 'requirement' (wich means, the App only works with Leanback/Android TV devices ) from being `true` to be `false`.

```
android:name="android.software.leanback"
android:required="false"
```

and Sideload it after that.

Answer (score 0):

We need to just make user features: leanback as required true to restrict only to AndroidTV on store:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />
```